# Can you add up front size at Preview?

Tags: macos, preview

**Preview** is a very useful application on OS X, for example, when I am previewing a .doc document, can I increase the preview's font size? <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preview is not actually opening the document for formatting/editing.

It opens a image of it, so no you can not change the font size, but you can increase the size of the image it self.